# First Order Logic: Express a statement about array elements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Im trying to solve a practice problem given by my professor on a class im taking about first order logic.

It asks us to express the following statement in FOL:

The smallest element in an array A is strictly larger than the largest element in array B.

However, I am confused how to find the 'smallest' and 'largest' elements, how do we remember those values in FOL?

The examples so far have been much simpler it seems,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $$∃s\,∃l\:∀x{\in}A\:∀y{\in}B    \;\Big(x\geq s \:\:\land\:\: y\leq l \:\:\land\:\: s>l\Big)\quad?$$

P.S. This translation is not really literal, as it makes explicit what was implicit in the verbal statement.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Though it should probably be x >= s and y <= l, but thank you!

Comment: Oh yes, the smallest element in an array or set containing the elements $3,3,7,8,9$ is $3$ (as elements are distinct, and repeat-occurring elements are single-counted), while the shortest stick (singular) among four sticks $A,B,C,D,E$ of respective lengths $3,3,7,8,9$ inches is neither $A$ nor $B.$ Shall edit the answer to change away the first two strict equalities.